# graphic won't work with AJAX data

Tags: jquery, ajax, dygraphs

I am facing a problem with dynamic fetch of data for dygraph.

My code looks like

```
var SensorID=$('.sensor-selected').attr('title');
var Sensor_Name=$('.sensor-selected').attr('name');
var Sensor_Type=$('.sensor-selected').attr('typ');
var begin=$('#fromdate').val();
var end=$('#todate').val();
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
   else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{   


         g = new Dygraph(
                        document.getElementById("graph"),
                        "file.csv", //change with xmlhttp.responseText
                        { 
                        labels:["Date",Sensor_Type],
                        title: Sensor_Name,
                        ylabel: Sensor_Type,
                        legend: 'always',
                        labelsDivStyles: { 'textAlign': 'right' },
                        showRangeSelector: true,
                         xAxisLabelWidth: 80,
                         xValueFormatter: Dygraph.dateString_,
                        axes: {
                            x: {
                                ticker: function (a, b, pixels, opts, dygraph, vals) {
                                    return Dygraph.getDateAxis(a, b, Dygraph.DECADAL, opts, dygraph);
                                },

                                axisLabelFormatter: function (val, granularity, opts, dygraph) {

                                    return formatDate(toDateTime(val));
                                }
                            }},
                        xValueParser: function(x) { return 1000*parseInt(x); },
                        xTicker: Dygraph.dateTicker
                        }
                          ); 

      }
   }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","fetcher.php?SensorID="+SensorID+"&begin="+begin+"&end="+end,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

}
```

if i  change csv file with the xmlhttp.responseText  the code will run crazy.
Sometimes is saying that the nr of column is not equal with no of label or it display yAxis is not defined or "2013-11-11" is not parsed like a date.

Instead.
If i put the Ajax response in a static manner it accept it.

I tried many formats like "2013-11-11 12:22:22,22\n" + ....
or without quotes or without \n . nothing works.

What i am missing? I repeat, for static data like quoted one is everything ok.

Maybe you can suggest a jquery solution.

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of code that's broken, preferably using http://dygraphs.com/fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/#&togetherjs=Uq20ra9nqE   i dont know to use that fiddle. hope this helps